# php curl shows non-readable signs

Tags: php, curl, character-encoding, decode

My Curl-code works:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$header = array(
  'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
  'Accept-Language: en-us;q=0.8,en;q=0.6'
);
$options = array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url, 
  CURLOPT_HEADER => 0, 
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, 
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header
  );
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$str = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But from one page only I get signs start so:

‹�������í}ëvâH²îïîµö;dk¦}™² ...

I detect with mb_detect_encoding that it is an utf8-string. I'm confused, why can't I read the source code like from other sites?

The site I want to curl is http://stores.ebay.com/artlines-2012

Thank you.

Comment: probably gzipped output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an encoding issue. Try adding `CURLOPT_ENCODING`.

Example:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
```